# How can I permanently prevent Outlook automatically switching to 'New' Outlook?

Tags: ms-office

I currently use 'old' Outlook, but Outlook will periodically (every 2-4 weeks or so) switch to 'New' Outlook without my permission, despite setting the title bar toggle to 'Off'. When I open Outlook, it tells me that 'New' Outlook will launch the next time it restarts and displays a message in a bar that cannot be closed:

[image]

[image]

When Outlook is restarted, it then attempts to reconfigure my mail accounts. I have to stop it from doing that, toggle 'New' Outlook to 'Off' again, dismiss the feedback dialogue box and then restart Outlook in order to restore it to how it was.

If it ignores my preference set by the 'New' Outlook toggle, how else can I prevent it from automatically switching?

I'm running Outlook for Mac v16.70 (23021201) on macOS 11.7.1.

Comment: Have a script that sets your preferences prior to calling Outlook.

Comment: This is Microsoft's way of saying, "get used to it, soon this will be the default."

Comment: No clue, if you find out, let me know. I temporarily went there to "try it out" and all it did was ignore all my subfolders and open only current mail. They and all software companies need to be put in their place. I won't be forced to use this new AWFUL version of Outlook.